# Proving this Riemann Integrable Property

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $g:[a, \infty) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is bounded in every interval $[a, b] .$ Let $c>a$ how can we show that if $g \in \mathcal{R}$ in $[c, b]$ for every $b>c$ and $\int_{c}^{\infty} g(x) d x$ converges then $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) d x$ converges and :
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x) d x=\lim _{c \rightarrow a^{+}} \int_{c}^{\infty} g(x) d x
$$
This looks like similar to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Henstock+integral#hakes_theorem

I tried to tackle this problem by trying to prove first that $g\in\mathcal{R}$ in $[a,b]$. But I don't know how to do that. I hope someone helps.

Comment: Your statement suggest that $c$ is some fixed point greater than $a$.  If $c$ could be any point such that $c  > a$  with $g \in \mathcal{R}([c,b])$ and bounded on $[a,b]$, then $g \in \mathcal{R}([a,b])$.  Which is it?

Comment: from the looks of it looks simple but I hesitated to believe that at first and thought that it might have required some decent proof, now for the second part of the proof I would hope to know a way to prove it

Comment: Do not delete your question right after it was answered. That is rather unfriendly towards the person who put in the effort to write an answer.